# Delete 2nd Duplicate Record in mySql Table

Tags: mysql

I have a collection of 2,00,00 rows datas in my MySQL table. Now i would like to remove 2nd duplicate record in a table. (i.e.), First record of a duplicate value should not be deleted. Delete only 2nd duplicate record in a table vale.

Example

```
id  |   logEntry    |   logValue
--------------------------------
1   |   AA15AA7515  |   11445588
2   |   AAFIRNNFIE  |   99586454
3   |   AA15AA7515  |   14589313
4   |   AA9894AF56  |   15985632
5   |   AA15AA7515  |   16124246
6   |   AA69481533  |   15454186
7   |   AAFIRNNFIE  |   12788549
```

In this example Id's (1,3,5), (2,7) contains duplicates. I would like to remove rows 3,5,7

Expected Output

```
id  |      Entry    |   Value
--------------------------------
1   |   AA15AA7515  |   11445588
2   |   AAFIRNNFIE  |   99586454
4   |   AA9894AF56  |   15985632
6   |   AA69481533  |   15454186
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: And you didn't do this in the first place when creating the database because? You should avoid this by making "Entry" unique.

Comment: @all: Thanks for the response.. now it get fixed now.. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delete from temp1 where id in ( select x.id from (select a.id from temp1 a,
 temp1 b where a.id<>b.id and a.logentry=b.logentry and a.id>b.id group by
 a.id) x );
```

This will work fine.

Check Here : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/825e0/1

Answer (score 5):

Try to this

```
Delete From table_name
where id not in( select min(id) from table_name
group by Entry )
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a table with duplicate rows – Somehow a unique index didn’t get created and a bug has added duplicate records to your table.

Needs to be alter the table by adding UNIQUE constraint.

You can use this query as follows:

```
DELETE from table1
USING table1, table1 as vtable
WHERE (NOT table1.ID>vtable.ID)
AND (table1.logEntry=vtable.logEntry)
```

You should run this query to make sure that no duplicate entries can occur further in the table:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT table_unique UNIQUE (field1,field2);
```

but you can do this if the table is empty.

or if records existed, try adding `IGNORE`

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT table_unique UNIQUE (field1,field2);
```

**NOTE: In case if you are inserting data using server side script (seems you are using php as tagged) then use validation of existence record in the table too.**

Comment: An explanation is expected to help future SO users who stumble upon this answer.

Comment: To make sure that the duplicate with the higher ID is deleted you should use `WHERE (table1.ID>vtable.ID)` ...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a pain in MySQL.  I would do this using a `left join`

```
delete t
    from table t left join
         (select min(id) as minid
          from table t2
          group by entry
         ) tokeep
         on t.id = tokeep.minid
    where tokeep.minid is null;
```